# iphone webview show html with images and css file

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I found some interesting URL http://cubiq.org/rotating-wheel-for-your-iphone-webapps which has rotational menu. Its good. It has html file along with images, css files etc.
In iPhone app, I copied (to root folder) all the files and imported to project. I'm using UIWebView's load request to load the html. But I'm not getting the rotatable menu.
Can some one post me the code (or tutorial or prototype or example) on how to use it?
Also let me know how to catch the even on click on "OK" button at the middle of the html.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

checkout IUI : http://code.google.com/p/iui/